# URL валидация regex

Tags: javascript

Какой regex должен быть что бы покрыть все эти кейсы, искал на разных порталах, но подходящего так и не нашел. Нужно пропускать только валидные урлы

```
http://localhost:8080
https://some-host-name
https://127.0.0.1:4545
http://load-balancer/some-path
http://load-balancer:8332
http://load-balancer:8332/some-path

http://localhost:8080/storage/v1/diag/ping
https://some-host-name/storage/v1/diag/ping
https://127.0.0.1:4545/storage/v1/diag/ping
http://load-balancer/some-path/storage/v1/diag/ping
http://load-balancer:8332/storage/v1/diag/ping
http://load-balancer:8332/some-path/storage/v1/diag/ping
```

Comment: вам нужно находить все строки целиком?

Comment: нет, нужно что бы каждый из этих урлов проходил регулярку (мне это для валидации инпута)

Comment: При такой формулировке вопроса регулярку `(.*)` пройдёт каждый из этих урлов.

Comment: @dev_jun Вам намекают что неплохо бы добавить примеры инпутв, которые не должны проходить валидацию

Comment: «Нужно пропускать только валидные урлы» — однако в вашем списке представлены не все возможные валидные урлы, например `unix://user:pass@/var/run/redis?0` это тоже валидный урл

Comment: мне кажеться покрыть абсолютно все возможные урлы очень сложно, по\тому предоставил список тех которые в приоритете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться конструктором [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL), но он пропустит не только http/https ссылки.
Впрочем, можно дополнить функцию проверкой [схемы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/protocol) объекта [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL).

```js
let urls = [
 'http://localhost:8080',
 'https://some-host-name',
 'https://127.0.0.1:4545',
 'http://load-balancer/some-path',
 'http://load-balancer:8332',
 'http://load-balancer:8332/some-path',
 'http://localhost:8080/storage/v1/diag/ping',
 'https://some-host-name/storage/v1/diag/ping',
 'https://127.0.0.1:4545/storage/v1/diag/ping',
 'http://load-balancer/some-path/storage/v1/diag/ping',
 'http://load-balancer:8332/storage/v1/diag/ping',
 'http://load-balancer:8332/some-path/storage/v1/diag/ping',
 'ftp://example.org/123',
 'my@email', // TypeError will be thrown
];

function isUrlValid(url) {
  try {new URL(url); return true;}
  catch(e) {return false;}
}

urls.forEach(url => {

  console.log(url, isUrlValid(url));
});
```

---

> Мне это для валидации инпута

Используйте `input[type=url]`

```js
const url = document.querySelector('input');
document.querySelector('button')
  .addEventListener('click', e => {
  console.log(url.checkValidity())
})
```

```html
<input type="url" pattern="https?://.*" required="required" value="http://???" />
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: Подозреваю, у автора нет готового массива ссылок, и задача в том, чтобы выдрать ссылки из текста

Comment: Заголовок вопроса таки говорит о валидации. И комментарий: "мне это для валидации инпута"

Answer (score 1):

Вот эта регулярка вам подойдет - `^http[s]?:\/\/[a-zA-Z\d.-]+[:]?[\d]{0,4}[\/]?[a-zA-Z\d\/-]+`.

Но как сказал @andreymal - при такой формулировке вопроса вам и (.*) хватит.

Единственное, что по факту определяет предоставленная мной регулярка - это схему.

Comment: Почему бы `[s]{0,1}` не упростить до `s?` ?